# Show implication of x and y generates a remeinder

Tags: arithmetic

I know:

```
1. If x is divided by 30 the remainder is 4.
2. If y is divided by 30 the remainder is 18.
```

Now the question is how do you show that x*y divided by 30 will give the remainder 12.

I know that I can brute force it, like so:

```
34/30 --> remainder will be 4, so x=34
48/30 --> remainder will be 18, so y=48
```

This gives:

```
(34*48)/30 --> remainder will become 12 which was to be proven.
```

However I'm wondering if there is a more "elegant" way of showing this, in a more logical way, rather than just guessing some numbers and putting them together?

Comment: the arithmetic would have been simpler if you had chosen $4$ and $18$ rather than $34$ and $48$

Comment: You have to understand that you did not brute-force anything, you did *one* example.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. But how do I show all examples? @ArnaudMortier

Comment: @J.W.Tanner has given you a perfect answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(30m+4)(30n+18)=900mn+540m+120n+72=30(30mn+18m+4n+2)+12$

Comment: $4\times18=72= 2\times30+12$